# Using prebuilt Qt binaries for MSVS 2008 with MSVS 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt

I have tried to use the pre-built Qt binaries for MSVS 2008 with MSVS 2010. (There are no pre-built binaries for MSVS 2010.)

This works fine for release builds, but with debug builds my Qt app fails to start with the error messages

```
The application failed to initialize properly (0xc0150002).
Click on OK to terminate the application.
```

and

```
LDR: LdrpWalkImportDescriptor() failed to probe
C:\Libraries\Qt\4.7.4\bin\QtCored4.dll for its manifest,
ntstatus 0xc0150002
```

Is there a work-around for this, or do I have to build my own MSVS 2010 binaries from the Qt source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no workaround, Visual Studio is not bent on binary compatibility (on the contrary).

If you don't want to build Qt yourself, you can always use the 4.8 beta binaries from [here](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/prereleases), they offer VS2010 builds.

Comment: Building the Qt binaries yourself isn't as bad as it sounds and is what I would recommend for 4.7.

Comment: @user763305: I wouldn't rely on it *always* working, technically it's undocumented behavior and certainly not encouraged.